# Replacing electrical wiring in masonry walls

Tags: electrical

An existing fully grouted 8" masonry wall has electrical wiring. The structure is more than 15 years old. Need to replace/upgrade the wiring to receptacles. Can I pull out the existing wires and replace with upgraded electrical wiring without compromising the walls.

Comment: Was the wall built using the conduit wiring method, or with multiconductor cables?  What is the reason for wanting to replace the wiring?

Comment: For a building over 20 years old which will undergo major renovation I want to be sure the existing wiring is not an issue when replacing wall receptacles and finding out the receptacles are not working.

Comment: Yes, what wiring method was used here? Was this wired using cables-in-grouted-chases, surface conduit/raceway, or embedded raceway?

Comment: 15-20 years is not “old” for wiring. There must be another reason this is caught your attention.

Comment: The wiring itself should last 50 years or more. Unless there is a specific issue don't waste your money and you time trying to replace it. Just replace the receptacles if you wish and move on with your life..

Answer (score 1):

If the wiring is in conduit you should be able to remove it without damaging the walls. If the wiring is by some other method you will not be able to remove the wiring without demolishing the wall or major repair work.